# Custom laravel error message for error/warning information added with host or other info

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I have multiple server for web and a server for data. For web server is having same git as the source. Both server write on same server data because the storage/logs are linked to the server data. I hope the explaination is not confuse.. Since the problem lies is about the log. The main problem is the log information. I need information about what server making a log. There is error that not known where the problem? I need to track this. More detail here: [https://pastebin.com/tmF0uCeZ](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
//MyLogger
namespace App\Logging;
 
use Monolog\Logger;
 
class MyLogger
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): Logger
    {
        return new Logger(
            env('APP_NAME'),
            [
                new MyLoggerHandler(),
            ]
        );
    }
}
 
//MyLoggerHandler
namespace App\Logging;
 
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
use Monolog\LogRecord;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
//AbstractProcessingHandler <- before
class MyLoggerHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    public function write( LogRecord $record): void
    { 
        $date = $record['datetime'];
        $pesan = $record['message'];
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $targetWrite = storage_path('logs/example.log');

        error_log("[{$date}][{$host}][{$url}] ".rtrim($pesan??" ")."\n", 3, $targetWrite);

    }

}
```

but if I have (give) error. I want the error goes to my error file.. Or added the URL, host in the error detail

The solution I give are like this.  I'm injecting the code on HandleExceptions.php

```
    public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0){
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $info = "{$host} {$url}";
        //injection start here
        if ($this->isDeprecation($level)) {
            $this->handleDeprecationError( $info.$message, $file, $line, $level);
        } elseif (error_reporting() & $level) {
            throw new ErrorException($info.$message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
        }
    }
```

source code: [https://pastebin.com/nzkuzq3H](https://stackoverflow.com) if posible to use custom as target for error?